# How to estimate certain parameters of an AR model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autoregressive

I need to estimate parameters of an AR model which is in the form of AR(1,11) it means that coefficients of AR orders from order 2 until order 10 are zero. How can I estimate these two parameters in `R` since `arima` function only accepts p as the order of the AR component. Note that this model has a different structure than Seasonal AR.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't this be possible by using the FIXED option in the ARIMA syntax? In this case,

```
output <- arima(x, order=c(11,0,0), fixed = c(NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA))
```

The `order` statement supplies the number of lags for the AR process, and the `fixed` vector is "NA" for any lags you want to estimate and zero otherwise.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know that we can assign "NA" for parameters that we need. I will try this.

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if that resolves your problem.

Comment: Yes it did but we should add another NA for q order like this  `output <- arima(x, order=c(11,0,0), fixed = c(NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA, NA))`